# Can you add a default description text to commits?

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I am using GitHub Desktop for Mac. I'd like to know if it is possible to add default text to commits.

For example, in the description of a commit, I'd like "[skip ci]" to be there by default in order to prevent Travis from building, unless I remove this default text, in which case Travis will then run a build.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing I don;t think can be done (I am not totally sure you can change default text as I could not do it in the desktop app but I could do it via a script in my terminal). However, if you are using Travis CI you could just add a git tag and make a small configuration change to your build and that will automatically trigger a build.
To do this you would need to add a git tag like such:

```
on:
  tags: true
```

Next you would need configure your build, I just created this sample:

language: nodejs

nodejs:
- 5.7.1

deploy:
  provider: heroku
  strategy: git
  skip_cleanup: true
  app: myapp
  on:
    tags: true
    nodejs: '5.7.1'
  api_key:
    secure: yourapikeyhere=

Travis CI has a nice [documentation about all the possibilities.](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#Conditional-Releases-with-on%3A)

Comment: What I need is to be able to force Travis to not run any builds unless I use a specific keyword (basically the opposite of using [skip ci]). By adding the keyword via a .gitmessage, this means I will have to edit the .gitmessage... Making it a cumbersome solution, even if working. So, no good. :/

Comment: We are attempting to modify Travis instead. No luck thus far.

Comment: Ahh, let me think about that one

Answer (score 0):

For standard git you can create a commit message template in `~/.gitmessage` and tell git to use it for every commit by setting `commit.template` in your user config.

```
[commit]
  template = ~/.gitmessage
```

I hope that your tool will pick it up also.

Comment: What I need is to be able to force Travis to not run any builds unless I use a specific keyword (basically the opposite of using [skip ci]). By adding the keyword via a .gitmessage, this means I will have to edit the .gitmessage... Making it a cumbersome solution, even if working. So, no good. :/

Comment: That is a different question and I don't know enough about travis to answer it. Maybe you should create a separate question for that. But please tell me: Did my idea work for having a default Text?